# C++ Core Guidelines Checker in Visual Studio 2017 Extension Tab missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im using Visual Studio Community 2017  Version 15.7.5 for C++ Development.

I wanted to enable the C++ Core Guidelines Checker. Strangely the Extension tab to choose between Release and Experimental is missing.

I only have the general tab.

Is this a limitation of the community version or a bug?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/08/11/c-core-guidelines-checker-in-visual-studio-2017/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is it got removed in the latets build of MSVC: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/03/13/c-code-analysis-improvements-for-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/